# how to port this postgresql lag statement to mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Imagine a table just filled with ID's and created timestamps, how would I convert this over to MySQL?:

```
SELECT created AS col_a , LAG (created) OVER ( ORDER by created ) AS col_b
FROM tester
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.created AS col_a,
       (SELECT created
        FROM tester AS t2
        WHERE t2.created < t1.created
        ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS col_b
FROM tester AS t1
```

or, use variables:

```
   SELECT t1.created AS col_a, t2.created AS col_b
   FROM (
     SELECT created, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rn
     FROM tester
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) AS var
     ORDER BY created) AS t1
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT created, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS rn
     FROM tester
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) AS var
     ORDER BY created
   ) AS t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
```

Comment: Wow, I was experimenting with the variable method and didn't know about the correlated subquery method.  I now see how this works.  Gratia!